# changing xml acitivies on button click

Tags: java, android, xml

This is my main activity and I'm having issues with the customer_layout.class and main_menu.class throwing an error. It keeps saying "cannot find symbol class customer_layout or "cannot find symbol class main_menu"

Here's a screenshot

[image]

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button CJB;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
//CJB = findViewById(R.id.button1);
      //  CJB.setOnClickListener(this);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
            public void customerPage(View v){
                Intent customerPage = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Customer_Layout.class);
                startActivity(customerPage);
            }
            public void loginPage(View v){
                Intent loginPage = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main_Menu.class);
startActivity(loginPage);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.andy.androidautoprototype.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:onClick="loginPage"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Main_Menu.xml and Customer_layout.xml are not classes, they are XML files.  You need to create the corresponding activities which will use those XML files as the content view.

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends Activity {}
public class CustomerLayoutActivity extends Activity {}
```

You could use fragments, but I don't know enough about your application UI hierarchy to make that call.  If you do go down this path you would create a Fragment class for each layout you want to use.

```
public class MainMenuFragment extends Fragment {}
public class CustomerLayoutFragment extends Fragment {}
```

Then inflate those layouts `Main_Menu.xml` or `Customer_Layout.xml` in the `onCreateView()` callback of the fragment class you're using.

Once that's done add a fragment container in your `activity_main.xml`, something like:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container">

</FrameLayout>
```

In your activity class, using the `FragmentManager`, instantiate your fragment class, and add it to a `FragmentTransaction`, `commit()` the transaction and it will be added to your fragment container.

Check out Android [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)s documentation for a more in-depth look, if you decide to go that route.

Answer (score -1):

Use `android:onClick` For when you click the button it will go to your activity, But Remember to add the java code. You cant just use `android:onClick` You have to have to java code for it to work.

Try the following:

```
    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="clickme" />
```

**NOTE:** Remember to import the view class.

JAVA(MainActivity.java):

```
    public void function clickme(View view) {
          setContentView(R.layout.[your_activity]);
    }
```

**NOTE:** `setContentView(R.layout.[your_activity]);` Do not put .xml after you activity name.

Check the documentation on this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Comment: In your java function it says that the function is required to have a return type. What would I return?

Comment: you should not return anything the function is void @user6680

Comment: I know void doesn't return, but see image for reference http://postimg.org/image/ir30hrr6l/